# N-1th Loop Elements are missing

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop, wpf-controls

Hi I am using below code to generate textboxes in WPF Applicaiton dynamically.

```
    for (int _row = 1; _row < 10; _row++)
        {
            RowDefinition rowDef = new RowDefinition();
            if ((_row == 4) || (_row == 7))
            {
                rowDef.Height = new GridLength(35);
            }
            else
            {
                rowDef.Height = new GridLength(30);
            }
            grdMain.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);

            for (int _col = 1; _col < 10; _col++)
            {

                ColumnDefinition coldef = new ColumnDefinition();
                if (_col == 4 || _col == 7)
                    coldef.Width = new GridLength(35);
                else
                    coldef.Width = new GridLength(30);
                grdMain.ColumnDefinitions.Add(coldef);

                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.Name = "txt" + _row.ToString() + _col.ToString();
                tb.MaxLength = 2;
                tb.Text = _row.ToString() + _col.ToString();
                tb.Width = 30;
                tb.Height = 30;

                grdMain.Children.Add(tb);

                Grid.SetRowSpan(tb, 1);
                Grid.SetColumnSpan(tb, 1);

                Grid.SetRow(tb, _row);
                Grid.SetColumn(tb, _col);
            }
        }
```

Controls are getting added but, only the 8th row is missing. This is strange.. Can you please let me know i am doing wrong..

[image: Here is the Image]

Comment: i dont know wpf but i your loops seems all right, is it possible that one rowdefination can be overlaped by other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached property are zero-based, when your loop start from `_row = 1`. With that you don't make use of `row=0`, and you don't have `row=9`.

And if you inspect the `Grid` at run-time using [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), it shows that row no.9 overlapping row no.8. Try to change your code to start from `row=0` and `column=0` like this :

```
Grid.SetRow(tb, _row-1);
Grid.SetColumn(tb, _col-1);
```

Then adjust your `if` conditionals accordingly.

Another tweak, with current code you have 9x9 number of column definitions which is a huge waste. Move `for` loop used to create column definition outside `for` loop to create row definitions (put it before) :

```
for (int _col = 1; _col < 10; _col++)
{

    ColumnDefinition coldef = new ColumnDefinition();
    if (_col == 4 || _col == 7)
        coldef.Width = new GridLength(35);
    else
        coldef.Width = new GridLength(30);
    grdMain.ColumnDefinitions.Add(coldef);
}
for (int _row = 1; _row < 10; _row++)
{
    RowDefinition rowDef = new RowDefinition();
    if ((_row == 4) || (_row == 7))
    {
        rowDef.Height = new GridLength(35);
    }
    else
    {
        rowDef.Height = new GridLength(30);
    }
    grdMain.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);

    for (int _col = 1; _col < 10; _col++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Name = "txt" + _row.ToString() + _col.ToString();
        tb.MaxLength = 2;
        tb.Text = _row.ToString() + _col.ToString();
        tb.Width = 30;
        tb.Height = 30;

        grdMain.Children.Add(tb);

        Grid.SetRowSpan(tb, 1);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(tb, 1);

        Grid.SetRow(tb, _row-1);
        Grid.SetColumn(tb, _col-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Thanks for your answer, i don't know how i missed that if i am missing 9th row, the issue would be clear, but i am missing the last but one..

Comment: you're welcome. It seems that if you do `SetRow()` to row number larger than maximum row definition available, WPF will put the object at the last row, hence you got 9th row at the same place as 8th row (max row number is 8, zero based). That behavior is kinda hard to predict without prior knowledge of it, so using Snoop as I mentioned in this answer is useful for this kind of situation.